# Syntax highlighting of RuleDelayed involving Orderless symbols

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I am using version 10.0.2

---

If I set

```
SetAttributes[ol, Orderless]
```

Then the following expression appears to be highlighted incorrectly after clicking in it (no need to evaluate it)

```
ol[a_, b_] :> {a, b} (*click in this expression*)
```

Of course replacements like this still work

```
ol[1, 2] /. ol[a_, b_] :> {a, b}
```

> ```
> {1, 2}
> ```

Am I correct in concluding that this is a (small) bug?

**Edit**: I tested this several times with a fresh kernel, but with a fresh front end the bug does not occur. I will try to see what steps I took to get the front end in this state.

**Edit2**

Can somebody please evaluate the following code in one cell and then manually type a space, to see if they get the same incorrect highlighting?

```
SetAttributes[ol, Orderless]
Cell[BoxData@
    RowBox@{
       RowBox@{"ol", "[", 
          RowBox@{"a_", ",", "b_"}, "]"
       }
     , 
     "\[RuleDelayed]"
     , 
       RowBox@{"{", 
          RowBox@{"a", ",", "b"}, "}"
       }
     }, 
  "Input"
  ] // CellPrint

SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Before, CellContents]
SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Next, Character, 11]
```

Comment: Heya @Kuba :). Em, well the a in the list was blue for me. But not after restarting the front end.

Comment: @Kuba Now only the `b` is blue for me :P.

Comment: It looks fine in Win7 V10.0.2 :)

Comment: @Kuba how about now? Remember to manually type a space!

Comment: Nice example but sorry, all fine. To cheer you up, from time to time brackets matching hinglighting stays on a screen for me. Don't know how to reproduce that at demand though.

Comment: @Kuba okidokie, maybe it is something mac specific then. It was pretty minor anyway :). We will have to find some other way to honor mr Fultz :P.

Comment: With the `CellPrint` code if I press space the `b` turns blue.  Backspace makes it green again, but as soon as I click somewhere else it's back to blue again.  This is in 10.1.0 under Windows.